# Ext Js - show/hide grid's header menu

Tags: extjs, header, contextmenu

How to control show and hide of the grid header context menu dropdown [ext js] through a javascript function on a button click?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I have found this workaround:

```
button.on('click', function() {
  var grid = Ext.getCmp('my-grid');
  // assuming that we need to expand the first column's menu
  var column = grid.columns[0];
  var hc = grid.view.headerCt;
  hc.showMenuBy(column.el.dom, column)
});
```